# WordPress Mobile Menu Not working

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu, navigation, nav

I'm not sure what happened or how it happened but one of our client websites mobile menu all of a sudden (at least I think it was all of a sudden) stopped working. I try to click on it and nothing happens (it's supposed to open a drop down) and I'm not sure how to fix.

I'm not sure if my brain is just fried but I've spent a few hours trying to trouble shoot, deactivating/uninstalling plugins (for conflicts), etc and nothing works. I've even tried replacing the menu with a WordPress plugin (MaxMega Menu) and that wouldn't work either.

The website is dgdoors.com.

Comment: If you have any specific code that you can post that works in one place but not another, please post it.  Otherwise, there are other places to find a Wordpress pro for hire.

Comment: I know and I am looking into that as well, I was simply hoping someone may be kind enough to try and help me resolve this quickly as I feel a more experienced developer will likely see the solutions in minutes.

Comment: I recommend rolling back to the last-known-good installation of the website that worked, and then trying to find the change.  I assume you use git or some other version control?

Comment: @multicolormedia I'm having the same issue...have you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin [WDES Responsive Mobile Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wdes-responsive-mobile-menu/) and hide or old menu from mobile.